# How do I see that for every self-adjoint and positive-definite $A$ there is an $S$ such that $A=S^*S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How do I see that for every self-adjoint and positive-definite $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ there is an $S \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that $A=S^*S$?

Is something that I am trying to prove but I am unsuccessful. It would be interesting for me to get an idea about how one could construct such a matrix $S$ just by knowing $A$.

Comment: With $S^\ast$ you mean the adjoint of $S$ right?

Comment: yes, indeed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every self-adjoint matrix is unitarily diagonalisable, so admits an orthonormal system of eigenvectors. On this basis the matrix becomes diagonal, with (because it is also positive definite) positive real entries. For such diagaonal matrices$~D$ the statement is obvious, as one can take for $S$ a real diagonal matrix whose entries are the square roots of the entries of$~D$ (this solution is far from unique, as one can throw in norm$~1$ complex factors independently in each diagonal coefficient).

That this solves your problem depends on the fact that the problem statement is invariant under unitary change of basis, which is the case. Explicitly, if $D=UAU^*$ is diagonal and $R^* R=D$, then with $S=U^*RU$ (that is $R$ transformed back to the original basis) one has $S^* S=U^*R^*UU^*RU=U^*DU=A$ (using that $U^*=U^{-1}$ for unitary$~U$).

Answer (score 1):

By just calculating it out. For example you can chose $S$ to be a upper triangular matrix. Then this is called [Cholesky-Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)